# Caption on the image hover effect in css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, overflow, css-transitions, css-transforms

Thank you all of your time in advance to share on my problem,

I having a problem of hiding the background color on the image, I tried to use overflow to hide the extra color padding over the image. I'm using bootstrap framework also. Here is the hover effect in this link.
http://www.bootply.com/JrP58sZHkg

Comment: Images are not displaying.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I replaced the images with color and you can still see there is the border is not hiding when hovering it.

Answer (score 0):

```
div img {
        background-color: #999;
    }
```

> Make background-color: none;

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that actually a picture of each box size, the div img is a pseudo img I put that for each photo only. If you remove it, the background-color text box color still here